# Usar Rowdeleting en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

quiero eliminar un dato de un gridview(se llama 'factura').
Que al momento de darle a eliminar obtenga los datos de la tabla, ejecute un delete en SQL y recargue la tabla. este es mi código, La verdad nos e como hacerlo.`

protected void factura_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

```
    string del_id_prod = factura.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    string del_prod = factura.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
    string del_marca = factura.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;

    cadena("delete from descripcion_fctura where id_producto = '" + del_id_prod + "'");

    datos_factura();
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Te envio una funcion rowdeleting de ejemplo en la que se toma un valor de una celda y que luego podrias utilizarlo

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    string del_id_prod = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
    string del_prod = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
    string del_marca = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text;

}
```

Puedes obtener asi todos los valores de tu consulta, los 3 que utilizas y luego ejecutar la consulta.

Recuerda una vez ejecutes la consulta recargar el GridView con nuevos datos para que desaparezcan los que ya estan eliminados

Comment: Eso ya corregí :), pero aun no puedo usar el row deleting

Comment: y obtener el dato de  una celda en concreto así como en el evento Selectedindexchanged:  id_prod.Text = productos.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;  algo como esto es posible en el Row deleting?

Answer (score 1):

con este código me funciono a mi, el BD es el modelo de base de datos y el Eliminar Empresa(Nit) es un procedimiento almacenado al cual le enviamos el parametro

```
int Nit = Convert.ToInt32(((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);
BD.EliminarEmpresa(Nit);
```